Set-cookie not working in when using axios
I have an app running in localhost:8080 and an instance of Directus (a headless CMS) running in Docker in localhost:8055.
I'm trying to make an API call from my app to Directus in cookie mode, which means when I make an authentication login call to Directus with the right credentials I should see a Set-Cookie response header that would create an access cookie on my browser, but this cookie is never created.
This is the login call I'm using:
const directusOptions = {
  email: 'email@domain.com',
  password: 'admin123456',
  mode: 'cookie'
}

await axios.post('http://localhost:8055/auth/login', directusOptions)
  .then(response => response)
  .catch(error => console.error(error.message))

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why is my access cookie not being created?
